# Why do Wordpress rewriites seem to work differently for posts vs pages?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am creating some simple rewrites in my functions.php file in my WordPress installation:

```
add_rewrite_rule('product1/faqs/?', 'index.php?name=product1-faqs', 'top');
```

I've noticed that if you hit "product1/faqs" in the browser, it successfully displays the content of "product1-faqs" but keeps the url as product1/faqs (which is desired) but only if it is a POST.

If I try this same technique but on a PAGE, the browser URL flicks to "product1-faqs" (undesired!)

Why is that? I don't want have to limit ourselves just to posts for the sake of rewrites working as desired...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a pretty simple solution - [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) utilizes the `name` variable for posts and custom post type posts. It utilizes `pagename` for pages, hence why `?name=product1-faqs` is not working. Use this instead:

```
add_rewrite_rule('product1/faqs/?', 'index.php?pagename=product1-faqs', 'top');
```

Comment: Hi there! The URL is still flicking to /product1-faqs when I hit product1/faqs. The behaviour doesn't seem to change?

Comment: Try running this in an `init` callback. If you are doing it in the base level of `functions.php` this may be happening too soon, thus not being at the top.

Comment: I think I'm doing that already. I have this in my functions.php file: add_action( 'init', 'productRewrites' );

Comment: Arh sorry - I think after the pagename change there was a caching issue. I think we are all working now!!!

Comment: fantastic! and yes, it looks like you are properly using the init action. You know what I meant, yes? if you do `add_rewrite_rule()` before WP actually runs it's own, WP will put all of it's rules at the top, over yours. :) Good old caching issues.